# What does this code print and why?

Tags: c

Can anyone please explain me why is this code printing 1 3 0 0 0 -1, and not 1 2 3 0 0 0? How does this call of define work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SOMETHINGDEFINED(i) A[i%4] 

int main(void) {
    int i, A[6] = { 1 };
    SOMETHINGDEFINED(1) = 2;
    SOMETHINGDEFINED(5) = 3;
    SOMETHINGDEFINED(4 + 2) = SOMETHINGDEFINED(1 + 3 + 1)--;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is 4 + 2%4 and 1 + 3 + 1%4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define` does a textual replacement, so

```
SOMETHINGDEFINED(1 + 3 + 1)--
```

becomes

```
A[1 + 3 + 1%4]--
```

Now you can see that modulo is only applied to last operand, not to the whole expression. You have to define the macro as

```
#define SOMETHINGDEFINED(i) A[(i)%4]
```

to correctly apply it to the whole expression.

Comment: Actually, I got a task like this. It asked what does this code print, and I tried to solve it, and then compiled it, and results from VS were different than mine. Tried debugging it and didn't get it, so...
Well, thanks Jack! :)

Answer (score 1):

`SOMETHINGDEFINED(4 + 2) = SOMETHINGDEFINED(1 + 3 + 1)--;` translates into `A[4 + 2 % 4] = A[1 + 3 + 1 % 4]--;` i.e. `A[6]=A[5]--;` `A[5]--` takes the old value of `A[5]` i.e. 0 and returns it, then decreases `A[5]`, then the assignment assigns the old value of `A[5]` to `A[6]`.

Comment: You're lucky that `1 + 3 + 1%4` is 5 and not 4, for otherwise it would be _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 1):

In C, macros are a simple text replacement. Do the replacement yourself (without inserting extra parentheses), or find out how to make your C compiler preprocess code without actually compiling it. This will give you enough information to understand this topic.

By the way, the example code is a great demonstration why you should not use C macros, as far as possible.